# Converting System.IO.Ports.SerialPort code to boost::asio

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm trying to convert a .Net code which communicates with a USB to TTL device to boost::asio::serial_port code to be able to run under Linux. I have done everything but there is a line that I cannot convert:

```
   port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSendXOnXOff;
```

What I've found is that we should use `asio::serial_port_base::flow_control`, but it's modes are only `none`, `software` and `hardware`. What should I do to make my code identical to the .Net code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want both software and hardware to match the existing.  I would assume the values can be or'd together to activate both kinds of control.

There are two kinds of handshaking that can occur with a serial port.  The first uses a pair of physical signal lines called RTS (Request to Send) and CTS (Clear to Send).  You should be able to see these lines in RS232 connector and cable pinouts.  As these are physical lines that must be attached, this kind of handshaking would be "hardware".  The other method involves sending specific bytes (XOn and XOff) to indicate when the buffer was getting full or when the device was ready to receive again.  Most devices or drivers provide this automatically now, but since it is done using the standard transmit/receive lines it would be "software".

With the rise in USB "serial ports", the distinction becomes a little less meaningful as it gets lost at the USB layer.  The USB to serial chips I have used with some of my devices do recreate the actual signals for the end device, but given the fixed number of pins in a USB connection, I assume all handshaking is done with USB layer data packets.